Name of this foil crimp connector?
Does anyone know the name and model of the crimp connector in the images below?
I have highlighted it in red. It is used to create a connection by piercing through conductive foil or film. The piercing tabs are then bent over the other side to hold the foil.
Thanks for the help! :)



gnawzguz - Hi, Where did the images come from? To comply with the site rule on referencing, details of the original source of copied / adapted material must be provided by you, next to each copied / adapted item. If the original source is online & public, please [edit] the question & add the webpage/PDF name & its link (URL) (e.g. website name + webpage title + its URL). If the source is offline (e.g. book, as it seems in this case, or private intranet) then [edit] the question and add full source details e.g. title, author, page, publisher, edition. TY

https://duckduckgo.com/?q=fpc+crimp+pin&iax=images&ia=images

@jsotola - Why did you add a duckduckgo link? Just posting search engine links is generally seen as passive-aggressive i.e. it's implying to someone they should have searched. I hope you're not trying to do that. For that reason, lmgtfy links are blocked, for example. And since you didn't address the OP in your comment, are you trying to suggest to me that your link is the answer to my comment? Please remember, for referencing purposes, a link to a specific webpage / PDF / book etc is required. The answer to that requirement can't be a search engine result. So please clarify your comment

@SamGibson it shows the name of the pin, and the OP can visually confirm that it is what they are looking for

@jsotola - I see. So in future, please (a) write enough to explain the purpose of a comment, so they don't come across as being snarky; (b) as always, avoid answering questions in comments; (c) use @replies in comments when possible, to avoid ambiguity of the intended recipient. || What you explained seems to be an answer-in-a-comment i.e. you're telling the OP the answer from that search term. Please avoid answering in a comment. Thanks for your cooperation.

@SamGibson Sorry for not complying to the rules of referencing. I'll take more care next time.
I don't think that jstola response is passive-aggressive, I think it's efficient and straight to the point, the right search is worth more than a thousand words.

@jstola That's perfect! Thank you so much! :D

@gnawzguz - "I don't think that jstola response is passive-aggressive" I'm glad you don't think so. However we know from lots of experience that, unfortunately, people have weaponised comments. Or to put it another way, short comments, including just a link to search results, can be seen as passive-aggressive as I explained. That would break the Code of Conduct and is therefore something to avoid doing. This is explained further in something I already linked above.

Try this search (*)
https://www.bing.com/search?q=TE+connectivity+%22FFC%22+crimp+terminal+pin+-socket
The fist result is a TE FFC crimp pin:
https://www.te.com/en/product-CAT-F439-P65127.html
Digikey has 20 different ones in stock: https://www.digikey.com/short/tdwz7mpw
(*) (As an environmentalist, I stopped using Google because how much energy is used to generate AI results.)

It's perfect! Thank you so much!
Also thank you for all the different references, they're very useful.
